# Julia macro splatting

Tags: julia

Why does this work:

```
function test_func(a, b)
  a + b
end

test_func((1, 2)...)
```

But this does not?

```
macro test_func(a, b)
  a + b
end

@test_func((1, 2)...)
```

Is it a bug in Julia?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Macros operate on **surface syntax**, so `@test_func` isn't seeing the result of the splat.  Instead, it sees the splat operation itself!  As always, a great way to inspect this is to quote it and see exactly what syntax the macro is operating on:

```
julia> :(@test_func((1,2)...))
:(@test_func (1,2)...)

julia> Meta.show_sexpr(ans)
(:macrocall, symbol("@test_func"), (:..., (:tuple, 1, 2)))
```

So the macro is only receiving one argument (not two), and it's an `Expr(:..., Expr(:tuple, 1, 2))`.  Notice that the tuple (1,2) *is* getting passed to your macro, but it's just hidden away inside the splat operation.  So you could dig into the `Expr` and kind-of-sort-of implement splatting yourself:

```
julia> macro test_func(as...)
           if length(as) == 1 && isa(as[1], Expr) && as[1].head == :... &&
                  isa(as[1].args[1], Expr) && as[1].args[1].head == :tuple
               a, b = as[1].args[1].args
           elseif length(as) == 2
               a, b = as
           else
               error("unsupported syntax $as")
           end
           return esc(:($a + $b))
       end

julia> @test_func((1,2)...)
3
```

But this only kind-of-sort-of supports splatting.  Look what happens if you try to operate on a variable instead:

```
julia> @test_func(xs...)
ERROR: unsupported syntax (:(xs...),)
```

There's now no way for the macro to know what it should be adding together!

Comment: "There's now no way for the macro to know what it should be adding together!"  That one sentence really helped me.  Thanks.